# Load SQL Server connection data from an XML file in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I am having a problem in my program when loading the connection information from my database I wanted to do it through an XML file as in the future it is easier when working with a large data structure, but still I have not been able to have a connection.
**This is my XML file**

```
<config>    <conn Host="localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" Sec="true;" Database="KYC5;"/> </config>
```

and this is what I have tried to do in my code

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "coneccion.xml")
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Dim nodeConn As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/config/conn")
Dim Host As String = nodeConn.Attributes.ItemOf("Host").InnerText
Dim Sec As String = nodeConn.Attributes.ItemOf("Sec").InnerText
Dim Database As String = nodeConn.Attributes.ItemOf("Database").InnerText

    Public cnx As New SqlConnection("server=" & Host & "integrated security=" & Sec & "Database=" & Database)
```

I hope for an explanation of how to fix it.

Comment: What does it do right now?

Comment: You've not explained a problem with the code you currently have. How are we supposed to help if you don't tell us what's wrong?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the database. You're trying to read string data from an XML file. Either you're getting the values you expect or you're not. If you are then the database stuff will work and if you're not then it can't. This question is purely about reading data from XML.

Comment: If you are getting the data you expect from the XML but the database connection doesn't work then the XML is irrelevant and it's simply that you're not creating your connection string properly. You should be using a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for that part regardless. So which is it? Are you getting the expected data from the XML or not? If you're not, what actually happens when you run that code? is an exception thrown or do you get data but not what you expect? If the latter, what do you get?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? With square sides? If you're using VB.NET then why aren't you using the connection strings supported by the application's .config file? Ref: [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning in the event that I have to update the code that does not affect the data in the database, since it would be tedious to be changing code for each individual client that uses it

Comment: That's not a valid excuse. You still have to be tedious by updating .xml files for each individual client.

Comment: I suggest that you use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) instead of concatenating the values in a string. It will take care of any quoting or escaping that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB is actually a lot better at reading XML than C# so you can take advantage of that. Here's a method that you can use to create an instance of the SqlConnection using the xml.

```
Private Function GetConnection(filePath As String) As SqlConnection
    Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath)
    Dim connString = xdoc.<config>.<conn>.Select(Function(x)
                                                     Return $"server={x.Attribute("Host").Value} integrated security={x.Attribute("Sec").Value} Database={x.Attribute("Database").Value}"
                                                 End Function).First()
    Return New SqlConnection(connString)
End Function
```

To call this it would be

```
Dim filePath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "coneccion.xml"
Dim conn As SqlConnection = GetConnection(filePath)
```

Although I agree with the above comments that if you are just reading the application config file, then use the built in ConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

**VB.NET**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<config>
            <conn Host='localhost\SQLEXPRESS;' Sec='true;' Database='KYC5;'/>
        </config>")
        
    Dim conn = xdoc.Descendants("conn").FirstOrDefault()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = String.Format("server={0}integrated security={1}Database={2}" _
        , conn.Attribute("Host").Value _
        , conn.Attribute("Sec").Value _
        , conn.Attribute("Database").Value)
        
    Console.WriteLine(ConnectionString)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;Database=KYC5;
```